# What is the right way to run TensorFlow 2.0 on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I used these commands to do that on my Windows 10 PC without AVX, support only SSE4.2, GTX1060 6GB with latest drivers:

```
conda create --name tensorflow-2.0 python=3.6
activate tensorflow-2.0
pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
conda install -c anaconda cudnn
```

Everything was fine until I tried to use TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Frut\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Frut\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Frut\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Frut\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Frut\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I tried another way:

```
conda remove -n tensorflow-2.0 --all
```

Deleted folder "tensorflow-2.0" in "Anaconda3\envs"

```
conda create --name tensorflow-2.0 python=3.6
conda activate tensorflow-2.0 && conda install -c anaconda pip
```

After that there were no errors, but active env is still "base *"

```
activate tensorflow-2.0
```

Now active env is tensorflow-2.0

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
conda install -c anaconda cudnn
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
```

And result is the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) currently advises to use this command to install Tensorflow2.0 with GPU support:

```
$ pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
```

In order to install it inside `conda` (provided you have CUDA enabled hardware) you have to install `pip` inside the environment first so:

```
$ conda activate your_environment && conda install -c anaconda pip
```

After that issue the pip command. If I were you I would destroy this environment just to be sure and create it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said, but still with no luck. I updated the post.

Comment: Well, I think you might be out of luck then I'm afraid. Some other things coming to mind: updating cuda to `10.0` (or downgrading to 9.0 if you have CUDA 10.0) and ensuring `CUDA_PATH` environment variable is set correctly. Does CPU version work correctly?

Comment: What `CUDA_PATH` should I use when install CUDA through conda commands? I don't use CPU version of TF. It is much better to do with colab GPU or even TPU from google.

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) and make sure your system is CUDA capable. Those are instructions for Windows, I'm not familiar with this OS enough so can't help with that. And __you should check__ CPU version of Tensorflow so one can pin-point whether this problem is GPU related or Tensorflow related.